# Posted on bulletin board will be overwritten

Tags: perl

Although using unshift, posts are overwritten. Please help someone.

What should I do?

How many lines should I write?

Is this harassment?

Usability is bad.

I've trimmed the code so far.

I can post.

```
print "Content-type: text/html; charset=Shift_JIS\n\n";

#form tag omitted.form processing omitted.

my %in;
my $alldata;
my $name    = $in{"name"};
my $message = $in{"message"};
my $host;

if ( $message ne "" ) {
    unshift @log,"$name<>$message<>$host<>\n";
    open(OUT, "> bbs1.txt");
    print OUT @log;
    close(OUT);
}

open(IN, "bbs1.txt") or $!;
while( <IN> ) {
    my ( $name_p, $message_p, $time_p, $zero_p ) = (split(/<>/))[0,1,2,4];
    my $log_p = "$name_p:$message_p<br>$time_p$zero_p";
    chomp $log_p;
}    
close(IN);
```

Comment: You've over trimmed the code - you're not populating or declaring `@log` any where

Comment: @Chris: `unshift @log` populates the array.

Comment: Excuse me. I cut the code too much. I am declaring @log

Comment: @Borodin only with the most recent message - there's no code to read in the old messages

Comment: @Chris: Version one of the question contains code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't load the previously written messages and put them into `@log` so when you come to add the latest message and write them all out, it will only contain the one message which is why you're seeing previous messages being overwritten.